# Phalcon mongodb cannot update

Tags: phalcon, mongo-collection

I can't update a document with Phalcon MongoCollection from Incubator 3.3
I don't get any error after save() but data are not updated.

My code is:

```
$category = CategoryModel::findById($id);
$category->title = 'uno';
$category->save();
```

I have also tried with incubator 3.4 and 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but after calling the singleton:

> MyModel::findById($id)

...the source collection I defined on the model constructor changes from **'myCustomCollection'** to **'my_model'**

I fixed it by adding some temporary code inside the **_getResultSet** method from app/vendor/phalcon/incubator/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/MongoCollection.php (Line 310)

```
$cursor->setTypeMap(['root' => get_class($base), 'document' => 'array']);

    if (true === $unique) {

        /**
         * Looking for only the first result.
         */
        $output = current($cursor->toArray());

        $output->setSource($base->getSource());

        return $output;

    }
```